# I got an error expected expression before '[' token

Tags: c

```
error: expected expression before '[' token
msg_ship_detroyed([FLEETSIZE].name);
```

Please help me to fix this error.
Thank you for your time.

Here is part of my code

```
typedef struct { int length; char name[20]; } Ship;
#define FLEETSIZE 3
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `[FLEETSIZE].name`? Without knowing this the only advice we can give is not to do that.

Comment: That doesn't look like C code.

Comment: [Edit] and show more code.

Comment: That produces an error because it is not C code. Please make a small program with everything needed, all the includes, the main function, etc. that demonstrates the problem. And importantly, tell us what you want the program to do. This one line you show here is so broken we have no idea what it is supposed to do.

Comment: looks like you're missing a variable name before the [

Comment: typedef struct {
        int length;
        char name[20];
} Ship;#define FLEETSIZE 3

Comment: Perhaps you want, for example, `msg_ship_detroyed[shipnum].name;` I doubt it should be `FLEETSIZE` which is perhaps the length of the array.

Comment: I did msg_ship_detroyed(ship[FLEETSIZE].name); but it say undeclared. How can I fix it??

Comment: Tim, show also how is defined `ship`.

Answer (score 1):

The tiny code fragment has a syntax error: `[FLEETSIZE]` cannot appear at the start of an expression.

Either you are not programming in C or there is something missing.

Posting a complete program would help diagnose this error in context.